# Проверка пользователя в node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt, аутентификация

Прошу вас ответить на несколько вопросов о проверке пользователя в node.js.

Как я понял, что используя JWT в качестве токена для аутентификации пользователя, следует иметь два вида токенов, access и refresh. Допустим refresh имеет срок жизни - 864000(10 дней), а access - 3600(1 час). По истечению срока годности access токена мы отправляем серверу refresh и сравниваем его с тем, что содержится в базе, если совпадает, значит генерируем новый access токен, затем генерируем refresh и отдаем все это пользователю, если не совпадает перекидываем пользователя на страницу входа, для того чтобы он ввел логин и пароль.

Вопросы:

- При попытке залогиниться должен ли генерироваться новый refresh token?
- При каждой ли передаче access токена, следует проверять наличие refresh токена у пользователя?
- Есть ли смысл шифровать токены при записи в базу?
- Есть ли смысл хранить access токен в базе? Потому как срок годности у него маленький и у сферического похитителя данных в вакууме будет всего один час на пользование токеном.
- Насколько вообще затея с JWT токенами имеет смысл? безопасно ли это? (учитывая то, что я не нашел толком руководств где использовали бы генерацию refresh токена, это наводит на мысль, что этим никто не пользуется).
- Что должно содержаться внутри токена и зачем? (id, логин или какая нибудь прочая информация.)
- Как более разумно или более правильно хранить токен у клиента? (Куки или можно использовать localStorage).